# Regex with negative lookahead to ignore the word "class"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-lookarounds

I'm getting insane over this, it's so simple, yet I can't figure out the right regex. I need a regex that will match blacklisted words, ie "ass".

For example, in this string:

```
<span class="bob">Blacklisted word was here</span>bass
```

I tried that regex:

```
((?!class)ass)
```

That matches the "ass" in the word "bass" bot NOT "class".
This regex flags "ass" in both occurences. I checked multiple negative lookaheads on google and none works.

NOTE: This is for a CMS, for moderators to easily find potentially bad words, I know you cannot rely on a computer to do the filtering.

Comment: Would you not want a negative look behind of just `cl`?

Comment: If you are looking for blacklisted words, why would you want to match `bass`?

Comment: Lookbehind is ok too. I want to match bass too so if people insert blacklisted words in other words, it can find them too. It's only to show them on the CMS anyway, so it doesn't have to be perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you're actually trying to use two lists here: one for words that should be excluded (even if one is a part of some other word), and another for words that should not be changed at all - even though they have the words from the first list as substrings.

The trick here is to know where to use the lookbehind:

```
/ass(?<!class)/
```

In other words, the good word negative lookbehind should *follow* the bad word pattern, not precede it. Then it would work correctly.

You can even get some of them in a row:

```
/ass(?<!class)(?<!pass)(?<!bass)/
```

This, though, will match both `passhole` and `pass`. ) To make it even more bullet-proof, we can add checking the word boundaries:

```
/ass(?<!\bclass\b)(?<!\bpass\b)(?<!\bbass\b)/
```

UPDATE: of course, it's more efficient to check for parts of the string, with `(?<!cl)(?<!b)` etc. But my point was that you can still use the whole words from whitelist in the regex.

Then again, perhaps it'd be wise to prepare the whitelists accordingly (so shorter patterns will have to be checked).

Comment: This will work, but it's inefficient, because the RegEx parser has to read three characters (`ass`) twice (or four times) every time -- once for the original match, and again for the lookbehind. If you use `(?<!cl)ass` or `(?<!cl)(?<!p)(?<!b)ass`, you get the same effect more efficiently.

Comment: It can be rewritten to prevent retracking (with atomics - `/(?>ass)...` or possessive quantifiers), but I actually think it may be optimized by the regex engine already. Anyway, that's not a big problem comparing to need to use similar checks for _all_ the words in the blacklist. That's when the hammer will fall. )

Comment: And it's better to use yours for this case in fact, since it is specifically looking for the word "class".

Answer (score 4):

If you have lookbehind available <s>(which, IIRC, JavaScript does not and that seems likely what you're using this for)</s> (just noticed the PHP tag; you probably have lookbehind available), this is very trivial:

```
(?<!cl)(ass)
```

Without lookbehind, you probably need to do something like this:

```
(?:(?!cl)..|^.?)(ass)
```

That's `ass`, with any two characters before as long as they are not `cl`, or `ass` that's zero or one characters after the beginning of the line.

Note that this is probably not the best way to implement a blacklist, though. You probably want this:

```
\bass\b
```

Which will match the word `ass` but not any word that includes `ass` in it (like `association` or `bass` or whatever else).

Comment: Should `youarethebiggestbass` be passed as a normal word here as well? )

Comment: @raina77ow: which pattern are you talking about? For the first two, they would match the `ass` on the end of the word. For the third, it would not be matched at all.

Comment: Of course it won't be matched. ) My point is that 'badword' can be used as a part of another word - yet so it would be clearly visible. )

Comment: @raina77ow: Frankly, that's why blacklists are a poor idea and are not a replacement for actual, human moderators. Better to allow people to sneak things in than to garble perfectly common and valid words.

Comment: And with that I agree completely. Languages are too... expressive, may I say, and there's just too much possibilities to use an expletive if one wants to. )

Answer (score -1):

Is this one is what you want ? `(?<!class)(\w+ass)`

Comment: That's not going to work, you're looking for any number of word-chars followed by `ass`, that's not preceded by `class`. So it would match `class` (which it's not supposed to do), and actually, since you've got any number of characters, the RegEx is free to include `class` in the `\w+ass` part and therefore nothing will ever be excluded by your lookbehind.